# How to get integer quotient when divide two values in c#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want get integer quotient when I divide two values. Per example

```
X=3
Y=2
Q=X/Y = 1.5 // I want get 1 from results


X=7
Y=2
Q=X/Y=3.5 //I want get only 3 from results
```

Comment: Do you need to handle negative numbers, and if so should they towards or away from zero? ( -2.3 -> -2 or -3)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `Math.Truncate`. This should do it.

Answer (score 31):

Integer math is going to do this for you.

```
int x = 3 / 2; // x will be 1
int y = 7 / 2; // y will be 3
int z = 7 % 2; // z will be 1
```

If you were using decimal or floating-point values in your equations, that would be different. The simplest answer is to cast the result to an int, but there are static Math functions you could also use.

```
double a = 11d;
double b = 2d;
int c = (int)(a / b); // showing explicit cast, c will be 5
```

Answer (score 9):

In VB.NET there is the integer division operator (\). It returns only the integer portion of the division. This comes all the way from the original Dartmouth BASIC so it exists in most forms of BASIC.

Comment: +1 for providing the VB-specific answer that everyone else ignored.

Answer (score 6):

try [Math.Floor()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.floor.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

try using simple maths

```
int X = 10 ;
int Y = 3 ; 
int Q = ( X - ( X % Y ) ) / Y  ; // ( it will give you the correct answer )
```

It works by subtracting the remainder beforehand from the first number so that we don't get a remainder at all !

Answer (score 1):

There is another elegant way of getting quotient and remainder in .NET using `Math.DivRem()` method which takes *2 input parameter*, *1 output parameter* and *returns integer*.

```
using System;
```

> **For dividend: 7 and divisor: 2**
>
> To get only quotient(q)

```
int q = Math.DivRem(7, 2, _);
//requires C# >= 7.0 to use Discards( _ )
```

> To get quotient(q) and remainder(r)

```
int q = Math.DivRem(7, 2, out int r);
```

`Math.DivRem()` has 2 overloads for 32-bit and 64-bit signed integers.